# How do I change Legend color in a Recharts pie chart?

Tags: reactjs, charts, pie-chart, recharts

I'm rendering a pie chart from `recharts` ([screenshot of the chart here](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screen-Shot-2023-06-20-at-19.01.51.png)).
I want every legend to be in a different color, but can't get it to work with the `fill` prop.

My code:

```
const COLORS = ['#000', '#3095B4', '#E6E6E6'];

<PieChart width={730} height={300}>
<Pie
    data={data}
    innerRadius="90%"
    outerRadius="100%"
    paddingAngle={0}
    dataKey="value"
    isAnimationActive={false}
>
    {data.map((entry, index) => {
        return (
            <Legend
                key={`cell-${index}`}
                fill={COLORS[index]}
            />
        );
    })}
</Pie>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Hey, @flow24, actually you want to change every cells color. so use <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index]} /> instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in your screenshot, You seems like to have different colors for every cells, not for legend.
So, use

```
<Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index]} />
```

instead of legend in your code.

Comment: Nice! Happy to help you, @flow24